# How do I configure the Github for Mac app so that it shows my local repositories?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I have been using Github with the bash command line so far. But now I would like to use the mac client. However, when logged in in the mac app it does not show my local repositories. The repos on github, however, show up.
I guess I will have to configure this in the app itself but i could not find any preferences to do this. Any ideas? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sidebar you should see "This Computer" as a header above the "Github" header.
Here you should have "My repositories". If you click it you can add a new repo with the + button at the bottom.

OR easier:

Hit "Command O" to open a new local repo. This is also accessible from the file menu.

Unfortunately there is no "automatic" way to add all your local repos as far as I can see.

Comment: Oh, there is no automatic way like there is for windows? Really?